# qApp->mouseButtons() always returns 0

Tags: c++, qt

I have Xubuntu 14.04 LTS and it seems that qApp->mouseButtons() always returns 0.

Here is a bit of code:

Class definition:

```
class Interface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
    // ...
    QListWidget searchList;
    // ...

    public slots:
    // ...
    void moveCard(QListWidgetItem*);
    void clickCard(QListWidgetItem*);
    // ...
};
```

Consructor :

```
Interface::Interface() : QObject()
{  
    // ...
    QObject::connect(&searchList, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(clickCard(QListWidgetItem*)));
    QObject::connect(&searchList, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(moveCard(QListWidgetItem*)));
    // ...
}
```

Slots :

```
void Interface::moveCard(QListWidgetItem* Item)
{
    auto buttons = qApp->mouseButtons();
    std::cout << buttons << std::endl;

    if(buttons & Qt::LeftButton)
        std::cout << "ha" << std::endl;
    else if(buttons & Qt::RightButton)
        std::cout << "ho" << std::endl;
}

void Interface::clickCard(QListWidgetItem* Item)
{
    auto buttons = qApp->mouseButtons();
    std::cout << buttons << std::endl;

    if(buttons & Qt::LeftButton)
        std::cout << "ha" << std::endl;
    else if(buttons & Qt::RightButton)
        std::cout << "ho" << std::endl;
}
```

So when I click and double click items, I always get 0 in the terminal, but never "ha" nor "ho". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090187/how-to-tell-the-mouse-button-using-qapplicationmousebuttons-in-a-click-slo

Comment: I found there:

"just see contextMenuPolicy property of QWidget. set it to Qt::CustomContextMenu, then you will receive customContextMenuRequested signal. Simply connect to it"

I did the first part, but I'm not sure what to do with the last part:

"then you will receive customContextMenuRequested signal. Simply connect to it"

:S

Comment: `QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(on_rightClickCard(QPoint)));`

Comment: But what am I to do with the QPoint instance? I'm interested in the QListWidgetItem instance. I'm sorry if I'm being too stupid.

Comment: I would like to bump this. I put some random printf in on_rightClickCard and it seems that it is never printed, ergo on_rightClickCard is never called. (Yes, I did declare on_rightClickCard)

Comment: Think about it: the clicked events are generated if the mouse button has been released already. So what you're seeing is expected. That's already explained in the dup. The second answer there is probably a workable solution. Did you try it?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? This is what I tried:

`QObject::connect(&searchList, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(clickCard(QListWidgetItem*)));
QObject::connect(&searchList, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(moveCard(QListWidgetItem*)));
searchList.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
QObject::connect(&searchList, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(on_rightClickCard(QPoint)));`

Comment: And this is my on_rightClickCard function:

`void Interface::on_rightClickCard(QPoint)
{
 std::cout << "test" << std::endl; 
}`

Nothing's happening, and I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Really I don't know what to do to get more help...

Comment: This evening I tried:

`class QSpecialListWidget: public QListWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT

 public :
  
 Qt::MouseButton mouseClickedBtnFlag;
 
 void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
  mouseClickedBtnFlag = event->button();
 }
};`

Comment: I declared searchList as `QSpecialListWidget searchList;` and I implemented clickCard as follows:

Comment: `void Interface::clickCard(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
 
 std::cout << "foo "  <<searchList.mouseClickedBtnFlag << std::endl;
 
 if(mouseClickedBtnFlag & Qt::LeftButton)
  std::cout << "ha" << std::endl;
 else if(mouseClickedBtnFlag & Qt::RightButton)
  std::cout << "ho" << std::endl;
}`

Comment: But I don't even get a foo. If I change searchList back to an ordinary QListWidget (and put the mouseClickedBtnFlag thing in comment in Interface::clickCard), I do get a foo.