# How can I detect middle clicks on PyQt QTreeWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt

The itemClicked/itemDoubleClicked signals don't appear to distinguish between left and middle mouse clicks.  I want to do different things depending on the which was clicked.  It appears that clicking happens on release so app.mouseButtons() reports NoButtons by the time my `itemClicked()` is actually called.

While I haven't tried it yet, I'm assuming I could do some main app mouse test to store the state globally, then read it from my `itemClicked()`, but this feels really convoluted and hacky, is there a better way I can't find?

[UPDATED] As suggested, I overrode the tree's mouse event.  I also didn't want to bother subclassing QTreeWidget just for this, so for completeness's sake, here is what I did:

```
setattr(self.tree, 'middleMouse', False)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.middleMouse = event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MidButton
    return QtGui.QTreeWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

self.tree.mousePressEvent = types.MethodType(mousePressEvent, self.tree)

def itemClicked(item):
    if self.tree.middleMouse:
        <do something>
    else:
        <do another thing>

self.tree.itemClicked.connect(itemClicked)
```

Python is the best.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3275153/1994235) C++ answer may help you but it is basically catching and storing the mouse state as you suggest, just not at a global level (it only needs to be dine within the widget you care about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to reimplement the mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * event) of the QTreeWidget and to change the behaviour depending on the button which trigger the event.

What you can do it with something like:

```
yourQtTreeView.mouseDoubleClickEvent = self.mymouseDoubleClickEvent

def mymouseDoubleClickEvent(event):
    #your code capturing the event
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it's the direction.